# Solve or disable MyFaces warning "HtmlRendererUtils WARN There should always be a submitted value for an input if it is rendered"

Tags: jsf, logging, jsf-2, myfaces

I'm using MyFaces 2.0 and RichFaces 4.3.7.

My task is to toggle between 2 panel groups based on requirement using ajax.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!someBean.renderOk}" id="firstpanel">
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.valueA}"></h:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.valueB}"></h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>


<h:panelGroup rendered="#{someBean.renderOk}" id="secondpanel">
     <h:inputText value="#{someBean.valueC}"></h:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.valueD}"></h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{calendarBean.popup}" >
<a4j:ajax event="click" render="firstpanel secondpanel" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<a4j:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="someBean.requestSave"  
render="@form" execute="@form" />
```

my backing bean is

```
public class SomeBean implements Serializable{

/getters and setters defined/
private String valueA;
private String valueB;
private String valueC;
private String valueD;

private boolean renderOk;

@inject
SomeDelegate someDelegate;


public void save(){
    if(renderOk){
        someDelegate.save(valueC,valueD);
    }else{
        someDelegate.save(valueA,valueB);
    }
}

}
```

> this is just some part of my code I understood that I cannot pass an inputText value as disabled or hidden but I cannot compromise on that. Is there any workaround to make values to be removed from submit queue.

When the form is submitting there is no problem, but warning messages are being displayed by MyFaces.

> HtmlRendererUtils WARN There should always be a submitted value for an input if it is rendered, its form is submitted, and it was not originally rendered disabled or read-only.  You cannot submit a form after disabling an input element via javascript.  Consider setting read-only to true instead or resetting the disabled value back to false prior to form submission.

The frequency of rendering and hiding input is very high and I'm afraid my logging file will be gigantic. How can I solve or disable those warning messages?

Comment: I miss the part where you submit the form and/or render the panelGroup. Might help to add the complete xhtml. My first thought is that you miss an "execute" in the component that initiates the rendering.

Comment: @MilovdZee my submit button is outside the panel group. im passing whole panel group to Execute.

Comment: Just in case this helps somebody: I had a similar issue with an own jsf component using a dataTable. I could get rid of the problem by wrapping the dataTable within a form.

Comment: my datatable is inside form

Comment: @HarishBarma, did you ever get rid of this problem?

Comment: @uresh No not yet

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass the panelgroup to execute without the id? I think it is good practice to give every component an ID. Also rendering a component with the rendered flag does not function because a component that is not rendered is not available in the JSF tree.
But as you say you are rendering the parent panelGroup and so that should work.

Comment: forget about  the code all i want to know is how to remove a component from submit queue based on condition

Answer (score 0):

To suppress [HtmlRendererUtils](https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/util/HtmlRendererUtils.java) warning logs on the WebSphere Liberty server, modify [traceSpecification](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/log-trace-configuration.html) attribute in server.xml:

```
<logging traceSpecification="org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils=severe"/>
```

Note that if traceSpecification is already defined, you can add loglevels for your module using colon(:) as a delimiter:

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=warning:javax.faces.validator=severe:org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils=severe"/>
```

---

For the WebSphere server, modify the 'startupTraceSpecification' attribute in server.xml:

```
<services xmi:type="traceservice:TraceService" xmi:id="TraceService_1183121908656" enable="true" startupTraceSpecification="org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils=severe" traceOutputType="SPECIFIED_FILE" traceFormat="BASIC">
```

Websphere supports config modification using scripts as well: [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=scripting-configuring-traces-using)

---

Note that the class path (`org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils`) can differ depending on the JSF implementation loaded.

Hint: The warning log usually contain the entire class path.